# Convert subquery to join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Is it possible to convert the following subquery to a JOIN, preferably without a derived table?

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_groups ug ON u.usergroupid=ug.groupid
WHERE
u.userstatus=1 AND
ug.groupstatus=1 AND
ug.grouprank>=(SELECT grouprank FROM user_groups WHERE groupkey='users')
```

The user_groups table looks like:

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| groupid     | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| groupkey    | varchar(8)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| grouprank   | smallint(6)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| groupstatus | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The users table looks like:

```
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| userid       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username     | varchar(32)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userpassword | varchar(32)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| usergroupid  | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userstatus   | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the scheme of the tables in question, or at least the `user_groups` table.

Comment: I've added both tables into the description.

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN user_groups` and then check `ug.groupstatus=1` in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this query?

Comment: LEFT JOIN is there as habit. It should be an INNER JOIN.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve all users with a rank higher than a certain value. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for -- give it a test.

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_groups ug ON u.usergroupid=ug.groupid
JOIN user_groups ug2 ON ug.grouprank >= ug2.grouprank AND ug2.groupkey = 'users'
WHERE
u.userstatus=1 AND
ug.groupstatus=1
```

Comment: Note: ruakh's answer also refines your query even further. It's worth reading his answer to see how you can improve your query even better than you asked.

Comment: I agree. Both are very similar and both work, however I've accepted yours as you answered first.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that exactly one `user_groups` record has `groupkey = 'users'` (since otherwise your query is invalid), your query is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT u.*,
       ug1.*
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN user_groups ug1
    ON u.usergroupid = ug1.groupid
  LEFT
  JOIN user_groups ug2
    ON ug2.groupkey = 'users' -- not a real join condition
 WHERE u.userstatus = 1
   AND ug1.groupstatus = 1
   AND ug1.grouprank >= ug2.grouprank
;
```

But note that the `LEFT JOIN`s actually end up working as `INNER JOIN`s, since your `WHERE` clause depends on the joins having succeeded. So you probably really want something like this:

```
SELECT u.*,
       ug1.*
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN user_groups ug1
    ON u.usergroupid = ug1.groupid
   AND ug1.groupstatus = 1
  LEFT
  JOIN user_groups ug2
    ON ug2.groupkey = 'users'
   AND ug1.grouprank >= ug2.grouprank
 WHERE u.userstatus = 1
;
```

Comment: Yes, groupkey checks for uniqueness so there's always only 1 value. Your query works too. Thanks :)